# WFLYEJB0406: No Jakarta Enterprise Beans found with interface of type

Tags: jpa, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb, javabeans

Can you help me please?

I'm deploying a simple application on windfly 27.0.1.

First, I have an interface called IGenericDAO:

```
package br.com.lucasatolini.dao;

import br.com.lucasatolini.domain.Persistence;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

public interface IGenericDAO <T extends Persistence, E extends Serializable> {

    public T cadastrar(T entity);
    public void excluir(T entity);
    public T alterar(T entity);
    public T buscar(E value);
    public Collection<T> buscarTodos();
}
```

I have an abstract class that implements the interface with generic persistence methods:

```
package br.com.lucasatolini.dao;

import br.com.lucasatolini.domain.Persistence;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class GenericDAO<T extends Persistence, E extends Serializable> implements IGenericDAO<T, E> {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    protected Class<T> persistenteClass;

    public GenericDAO(Class<T> persistenteClass) {
        this.persistenteClass = persistenteClass;
    }

    public T cadastrar(T entity) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public void excluir(T entity) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        if (entityManager.contains(entity)) {
            entityManager.remove(entity);
        } else {
            T managedCustomer = entityManager.find(this.persistenteClass, entity.getId());
            if (managedCustomer != null) {
                entityManager.remove(managedCustomer);
            }
        }

    }

    public T alterar(T entity) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        entity = entityManager.merge(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public T buscar(E valor) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        T entity = entityManager.find(this.persistenteClass, valor);
        return entity;
    }

    public Collection<T> buscarTodos() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        List<T> list =
                entityManager.createQuery(getSelectSql(), this.persistenteClass).getResultList();
        return list;
    }

    public String getSelectSql() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("SELECT obj FROM ");
        sb.append(this.persistenteClass.getSimpleName());
        sb.append(" obj");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Every entity in my system implements the abstract class as the "Cliente" class:

```
package br.com.lucasatolini.dao;

import br.com.lucasatolini.domain.Cliente;
import jakarta.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public final class ClienteDAO extends GenericDAO<Cliente, Long> implements IGenericDAO<Cliente, Long> {
    public ClienteDAO() {
        super(Cliente.class);
    }
}
```

And I use the Bean in my Servlet:

```
package br.com.lucasatolini.controllers;

import br.com.lucasatolini.dao.IGenericDAO;
import br.com.lucasatolini.domain.Cliente;

import jakarta.ejb.EJB;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;

@Named
public class ClienteController extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    public IGenericDAO clienteDAO;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Cliente c = new Cliente("Lucas", 100_100_100_10L, 11_90000_0000L,
                "Rua Bronze", 383, "Barueri", "SP");
        this.clienteDAO.cadastrar(c);
        resp.getWriter().print(c.getId());
    }
}
```

When trying to deploy the following error occurs:

```
Dispatcher error: {
  "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Vendas.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"Vendas.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0406: No Jakarta Enterprise Beans found with interface of type 'br.com.lucasatolini.dao.IGenericDAO' for binding br.com.lucasatolini.controllers.ClienteController/clienteDAO"},
  "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"Vendas.war\".WeldStartService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"Vendas.war\".beanmanager"
  ],
  "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"Vendas.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"Vendas.war\".beanmanager]",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"Vendas.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"Vendas.war\".WeldStartService, jboss.deployment.unit.\"Vendas.war\".beanmanager]"
  ]
}
```

I have an empty beans.xml file inside the META-INF directory.

I already tried changing the Windfly version to 24.0.0. The error persists:

```
Dispatcher error: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Vendas.war\".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link br/com/lucasatolini/controllers/ClienteController (Module \"deployment.Vendas.war\" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServlet"}}
```

I've tried everything!
Really, I don't know the problem.

Comment: Having the same problem and I can't find any resource that can help. Did you find a solution?